# Como reemplazar signo de cierre de parentesis en javascript

Tags: javascript

como reemplazar el simbolo de cierre de parentesis  usando new RegExp
Estoy intentando hacer de la siguiente manera y me da error

```
var string = "(hola)"; console.log(string.replace(new RegExp(')'),'g'),'&#41'));
```

> //me genera el siguiente error (index):173   Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group

Comment: Las expresiones regulares usan paréntesis para crear grupos, así que cuando quieres buscar el carácter `(`o `)` tienes que *escaparlo* con un `\ ` delante: `\(`

Answer (score 1):

Si se trata de reemplazar el paréntesis de cierre, puedes intentar esto:

```js
var string="(hola)";
var newString=string.replace(/\)/g, "&#41");
console.log(newString);
```

Cuando en la expresión regular intervienen caracteres reservados (entre los cuales está el paréntesis de apertura o de cierre), los mismos deben ser escapados poniendo delante el caracter de escape `\`.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, pero te falta explicar el por qué

Answer (score 0):

Mirando el problema de manera más general, se puede hacer una función que reciba el texto y el caracter a reemplazar. Mirando que el reemplazo es por `41`, veo que coincide con su valor en decimal del *ASCII*.

Primero se obtiene el valor en decimal del caracter, luego se crea una expresión regular que reemplaza el valor hexadecimal y luego se lo reemplaza por el decimal. Esto se hace escapando con una barra invertida seguido de una `x` y luego el número, ejemplo, `\x29`, `2 * 16 + 9` es `41`.

```js
function reemplazar(texto,caracter)
{
  var dec = caracter.charCodeAt()
  var hex = (dec+256).toString(16).slice(1)
  var exp = new RegExp("\\x"+hex,"g")
  return texto.replace(exp,"&#"+dec)
}
var string = "(hola)"
var string_2 = string
string_2 = reemplazar(string_2 ,")")
console.log(string_2)
```